# SignalR multiple client side event handling

Tags: javascript, signalr

Very new to both javascript, signalR and c# in general.

I have 2 functions on client side which I want to call in different times and I can only get 1 to fire.

Javascript portion:

```
var connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder().withUrl("/signalRHub").build();


    connection.on("DisplayCardEvent", function (message) {
        document.getElementById("EventMessage").innerHTML = message;
    });

    connection.on("DisplayCardInfo", function (idCode, givenName, surName){
        document.getElementById("IdCode").innerHTML = idCode;
        document.getElementById("GivenName").innerHTML = givenName;
        document.getElementById("SurName").innerHTML = surName;
    });

    connection.start().catch(err => console.error(err.toString()));
```

Html code:

```
<div id="EventMessage"></div>
<div id="IdCode"></div>
<div id="GivenName"></div>
<div id="SurName"></div>
```

On server side when i call:

```
_hubcontext.Clients.All.SendAsync("DisplayCardEvent", eventName);
```

It fires perfectly by replacing contents in the div box EventName but when i call:

```
_hubcontext.Clients.All.SendAsync("DisplayCardInfo", idCode, givenName, surName);
```

The event on client side never fires. When inspect the broswer it only shows the first one as an event it listens.

Edit: Managed to solve the problem. The issue was that the broswer I was using to run the app cached the javascript file previously. As I added second function it was never updated on browser side. The fix was to simply delete browser cache.